# Combination Lock Program

Tags: python

Me and my partner have been working on this for a few hours and can't figure this out. The directions are vague in some areas and our professor did not do a good job of breaking it down to help us. Here is a link to the directions. I believe they are not very clear but please correct me if I am wrong and just overthinking it https://i.stack.imgur.com/Avh0N.jpg

I believe that our biggest problems are the unlock(combination) and set_new_combination(new_combination) methods. I can figure out the **str**() method as that one isn't very hard to do. We've tried the things our professor has told us to try but they have been unsuccessful.

```
class Lock:
    def __init__(self, combination = 0):
        self.combination = combination
        self.locked = False

    def lock(self):
        self.locked = True

    def unlock(self, combination):
        if combination == True or combination == 0:
             self.locked = False

    def set_new_combination(self, new_combination):
        if self.locked == False:
            self.combination = new_combination

   def is_locked(self):
        if self.locked == True or self.combination == True:
            return True
        else:
            return False

    def __eq__(self, other):
        if other is not None and type(other) == type(self):
            if self.combination == other.new_combination:
                return False

    def __str__(self):
        return self.combination, ',', self.locked
```

The expected result should be a working basic combination lock.

Comment: "The directions are vague in some areas and our professor did not do a good job of breaking it down to help us." - I disagree, I think the instructions are clear enough, which points do you think are vague?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's my implementation based on the inctructions provided, with comments where it deviates from your code.

```
class Lock:
    def __init__(self, combination = 0):  # No change here
        self.combination = combination
        self.locked = False

    def lock(self):
        # Although a test of self.locked is redundant, the instructions state
        # "...if invoked a second time this, method should do nothing."
        if not self.locked:
            self.locked = True

    def unlock(self, combination):
        # You were not testing the stored combination against the one passed to the method.
        # it does not matter if the stored combination is zero or a different number,
        # you still need to check for equality.
        # You also need a test as with lock() to satisfy the "if invoked a second time this, 
        # method should do nothing" requirement.
        if self.locked and self.combination == combination:
            self.locked = False

    def set_new_combination(self, new_combination):
        # You can simply the `if` condition, there's no need to test against False
        if not self.locked:
            self.combination = new_combination

    def is_locked(self):
        # I don't know why you are testing the self.combination value, you 
        # only need to return the state of the lock   
        return self.locked

    def __eq__(self, other):
        # You have the correct guard conditions but were returning False when 
        # the combinations matched. You can simply return the comparison result.
        if other is not None and type(other) == type(self):
            return self.combination == other.new_combination

    def __str__(self):
        # For some reason the output format specified for this appears to put it in a list
        # (the square brackets) but as it's only for display we'll "fake" the list.
        # The `if` statement prints the word 'locked' or 'unlocked' depending on the 
        # `self.locked` state.
        return '[{}, {}]'.format(self.combination, 'locked' if self.locked else 'unlocked')
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `unlock`method is trying to compare a boolean to a number (the combination). Change it to look like this:

```
def unlock(self, combination):
    if combination == self.combination:
         self.locked = False
```

You also did this in your `is_locked` method, so that should be changed too:

```
def is_locked(self):
    return self.locked
```

(Any time you find yourself writing something along the lines of `if x return True else return False` you can almost always replace this with `return x` if the conditional is simple).

`set_new_combination` works fine; I don't know what issue you saw with it.

Finally, your `__str__` method should actually return a string:

```
def __str__(self):
    return '[' + str(self.combination) + ', ' + 'locked' if self.locked else 'unlocked' + ']'
```

Comment: The `__str__` method needs to return the word "locked" or "unlocked" after the combination, your code will return "True" or "False"

Comment: Good catch; fixed

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of problems with your code. First, if statement in your unlock method will be executed only if `combination == 0 or combination == 1`, which has nothing to do with lock's combination (`self.combination`). In your is_locked method you should only return `self.locked`, no need for `if`. `__eq__` method can also be simplified. And `__str__` method should actually return String.

```
class Lock:
    def __init__(self, combination = 0):
        self.combination = combination
        self.locked = False

    def lock(self):
        self.locked = True

    def unlock(self, combination):
        if self.combination == combination:
             self.locked = False

    def set_new_combination(self, new_combination):
        if not self.locked:
            self.combination = new_combination

    def is_locked(self):
        return self.locked

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return isinstance(other, Lock) and self.combination == other.combination

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.combination}, { "locked" if self.locked else "unlocked"}'
```

Comment: The `__str__` method needs to return the word "locked" or "unlocked" after the combination, your code will return "True" or "False"